# Offline Wireshark install

Tags: software-installation, offline, wireshark

I am looking for a way to install wireshark on a machine that has no internet connection.

Is there a binary that I didn't see on the download page?

Is there any option, other than building from source?

Will building from source provide the required dependencies?

Comment: Building from source does *not* provide the required dependencies, and you still need to download a number of packages to get full Wireshark support (including all the Qt libraries, nowadays), and that can get tricky quickly.

Comment: Any suggestions as to where the binary can be obtained?

Comment: @ThomasWard: unless you decide to pass the `static` flag to the compiler.

Comment: @Helio true, but you need to compile on a networked computer that has the dependencies, if OP only has the offline system they can't even do that.

Comment: @ThomasWard: true.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use an [AppImage](https://appimage.org) of WireShark, as it should come with all the dependencies inside.

The creator of the AppImage format provides an up-to-date build here: https://bintray.com/probono/AppImages/Wireshark